# How to read this operator declaration and implementation?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

The code in question:

```
struct PCArea {
        PCArea(
            int minxx = 0, 
            int minyy = 0, 
            int maxxx = 0, 
            int maxyy = 0
        ) {}
    };

struct NDCVolume {
    NDCVolume() {}

    operator PCArea() const;
};

// how does this operator work? how to use/read it?
NDCVolume ::operator PCArea() const {

    return PCArea(iminx, iminy, imaxx, imaxy); 
}
```

Redundant code has been removed from the snippet. I have used Visual Studio > Find All References but cannot spot any where it is being used. To me, it looks like a member method without a specified return value.

How is this different from below?

```
PCArea NDCVolume::PCArea() const;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a conversion operator.

In case of `NDCVolume NDCVolume::PCArea() const;` it's just a function and will not be used implicit

in case of conversion operator defined you can write

```
NDCVolume vol;
PCArea area = vol; //implicit conversion
```

in the second case (with regular function) you will have to make it explicit:

```
NDCVolume vol;
PCArea area  = vol.PCArea(); //explicit conversion
PCArea area2 = vol; //error, if no conversion operator is defined
```

Comment: now i have to check whether can implicit convert and assign to a PCArea& area.

Comment: @Jake: don't do that for reference. Because you will bind reference to local variable. But you can bind the result to `const &` - in that case object lifetime will be prolonged

Answer (score 0):

implicit conversion operator to type PCArea.

```
PCArea NDCVolume::PCArea() const;
```

is only function, not conversion operator, cannot be used automatically.